# Product Flavors Configurations in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I am completely new to `Product Flavors` and I have gone through many links to understand it. But there are few doubts which are still not clear. I am having 3 product flavors i.e: `qa`, `dev` and `prod`. I have only created these three product flavors because I need to change the URLs and some API keys for different flavors which I have done by creating 3 different packages and placing the same `java`(having the URLs) file in the `app/src` directory. This is how my `build.gradle`. What are the mandatory things I need to add in each flavor? Something related to: `proguard`, `signingConfigs`:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    flavorDimensions "default"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sagar.demo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 67
        versionName "1.0.0" //Update Version build number
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {

        release {
            storeFile file("myKeystore")
            storePassword "Keystore2017"
            keyAlias "SagarSuri"
            keyPassword "Keystore2020"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false  // shrink
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    productFlavors {

        qa {
            dimension "default"

        }
        prod {
            dimension "default"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        dev {
            dimension "default"

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't state your problem and your question is very vague. "Mandatory" could be very subjective and depends on a lot of aspects.

Comment: I am just trying to generate 3 product flavors. Do I need to separately define proguard rules file for the flavors ? Or is there anything that I am missing to add in each product flavors in `gradle`. @ahasbini

Comment: unrelated but `org.apache.http.legacy` so sad....

Comment: should I remove that? I am not sure about it. It came autogenerated. Can you explain a little bit about that please. Curious to learn @An-droid

Comment: It's deprecated code https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client . You should concider using libs like okhttp or better retrofit

Comment: I am using `Volley` in the project. Is it fine ? @An-droid

Comment: I guess it is, I used it years ago and it was fine for a simple use. But if you can get used to retrofit it can be a good start to cleaner code, if you want to improve. And once you are used  to it, it rocks (cf : if you use volley I don't think apache lib is relevant)

Comment: Thank you so much for your great suggestion. @An-droid

Comment: No prob, but I get 404 from our link

Comment: I fixed the problem so deleted the question.. Thank you so much for the help and suggestion @An-droid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way product flavors work is such that you'll end up with the number flavors in each `dimension` multiplied by the number of `buildTypes`, in your case you have 3 flavors in a single dimension and 2 build types which ends up with 3x2=6 build variants which are the following:

- qaDebug
- qaRelease
- prodDebug
- prodRelease
- devDebug
- devRelease

Each combination is an actual combination of the related product flavor config and the related build type config combined. Meaning for variant `qaDebug`, it's configuration are from the defined under `qa` and from the defined under `debug` combined. Hence if `debug` already defines the `proguardFiles` there's generally no need to define it in `qa`, unless if `qa` requires extra proguard configs for it's own code then that's a different matter that needs to be decided and hence proguard should be defined specific for each flavor and not in the build types.

Another aspect I'd like to point out is `signingConfig` which here is defined the same value for `prod` and `release`. This means that any combination that starts with `prod` or ends with `Release` will have the `signingConfig` set, which in this case are: `qaRelease`, `prodDebug`, `prodRelease` and `devRelease`.

Hence the configuration is really up to your choice and design, and not all projects will have the same config.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got my doubts cleared. So I dont even need to put signingConfig in my `prod ` product flavors. Because by default release `buildType` has it.